# Must all parts of Hatarat Nedarim be said in a language which we understand, or only some parts?

Tags: halacha, rosh-hashanah-new-year, beit-din-court, language, nedarim-shevuot

## Introduction

Before Rosh Hashanah, it's customary to do the "annulment of vows" ceremony.  There are good reasons for this ceremony.  Though the ArtScroll Siddur commentary warns:

> Annulment is valid only if the vows involve just oneself.  If, however, the vows were adopted for the sake of, or involve, someone else, they cannot be annuled without the consent of the other party.

## My question

R' Doniel Neustadt [writes](http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5758/nitzavim.html) that hatarat nedarim (hatoras nedorim / "annulment of vows") must be said in a language which we understand:

> For the annulment to be valid, the petitioner and the members of the court must understand exactly what is being said.  Anyone who does not understand the published Hebrew text should annul his or her vows in English.  (Chayei Adam 138:8; [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 128](http://www.yonanewman.org/kizzur/kizzur128.html):16.)

Does this apply only to the part which the petitioner says?  Or — as I would assume is true from the text "and the members of the court" — does it also apply to the response which the court of three says in reply?

Comment: FWIW, my rav has everyone recite it in English - all parts, from what I recall. I'll see if I can ask him this question tomorrow. Though, it may more likely be on Shabbat when I can ask him anything at all. He's busy "performing", tomorrow.

Comment: @DanF: Please let us know. The answer might come in handy next Elul. :)